# Why does linux scan my cdrom on boot?

Tags: linux, boot, gentoo, data-cd

My linux system scans my cdrom on boot. Can I disable that feature without removing my cdrom tray?

Comment: Are you sure it's Linux doing it and not your BIOS (or possibly bootloader)?

Comment: @Mat , i hear that noise twice , one done by BIOS , one after ram disk is loaded

Comment: The "scan" might just be the CD-rom's self-test happening when the driver loads and asks it how it's doing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are running LVM, or have the LVM tools installed, it will scan for LVM devices during the init sequence. This is controlled by the lvm config file (`/etc/lvm/lvm.conf` on Debian).

The config file may have a commented-out line to exclude `/dev/cdrom` from its scan. Check this and uncomment it, or substitute a different device name if you don't have `/dev/cdrom`.

In the `devices` section, you want a line like:

```
filter = [ "r|/dev/cdrom|" ]
```

Comment: yeah , i do have LVM root , i'll take a try soon

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `filter = [ "a|/dev/sda2|", "r/.*/" ]` or the like to only include the device(s) that contains the LVM partitions.

Answer (score 0):

Another one guilty of doing these things might be some kind of hardware-scan-process. In RH/clones this is **kudzu**. I am not sure if gentoo has a similar startup process that scans for new/changed hardware.